# All spaces are occupied using RTABmap stereo

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to map the area using the stereo camera and after looking at produced map, all the cells are black, meaning occupied. I have tried to figure out for 2 days but still struggling to understand the reason.

Will it be possibe for someone to have a look at my database? I clearly doing something wrong. Also, as soon as I start RTABmap, the framerate drops to 20 hz from 30 hz and the images lag.

My RTAB database:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSgHQdynvplid1pwU9MlEqqmyx8TJFc6/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319346/all-spaces-are-occupied-using-rtabmap-stereo/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera is looking up. There is a missing optical rotation that could be fixed by rotating the base frame of the camera:

```
<arg name="pi/2" value="1.5707963267948966" />
<arg name="optical_rotate" value="0 0 0 -$(arg pi/2) 0 -$(arg pi/2)" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_base_link" args="$(arg optical_rotate) base_link stereo_camera 100" />
```

Then make sure to set `frame_id` parameter of rtabmap to `base_link` (or whatever is your robot base frame).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0